# Import data from Excel into SQL

Tags: sql, excel, openrowset

I am trying to import data from Excel into SQL.

I had already done this before one year with OPENROWSET.

```
SELECT A.surname 
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\temp\test.xlsx', [roi$]) AS A
```

I am running this code and it gets stuck on executing the query.

I am using office 2007.

Comment: if you mean by "stuck" that it the code is not moving past this statement in the debugger, then maybe you have the Excel file open, otherwise, I think you should get an run-time error. Use try/catch with manual debugging to fully understand the problem.

Comment: **SQL** is just the query **language** - it's not a product - so you cannot *insert into SQL* - that just doesn't make any sense. Please add a relevant tag for a **concrete RDBMS** (`mysql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` etc.) to make it clear what you really use

Comment: I just wait 30 minutes and i have no result. The datasheet have only 10 records. 
I try the try/catch  but not manual debugging
 i think.

I will try oslo the relevant tag.

I know that is a query language but i was write this query in the past and working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly ...
I solved it by creating an instance of ADODB.Connection with which I connect to the ActiveWorkbook and ActiveWorkSheet and then load the data from Excel into a RecordSet.
Go see my post which is a very similar problem:

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029012/load-aggregate-data-from-excel-into-adodb-recordset)